# In MongoDB, is it possible to use $set or $mul but specify another field in the same document rather than a constant?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say that I have a document:

```
{ _id: 1, item: "ABC", supplier: "XYZ", price: 10, available: 23 }
```

and then I run something like

```
db.products.update(
   { _id: 1, supplier: "XYZ" },
   { stock_value: {$mul: ["price", "available", 0.8] }}
)
```

to get a document

```
{ _id: 1, item: "ABC", supplier: "XYZ", price: 10, available: 23, stock_value: 184 }
```

I'd like to do this without loading everything into the client. And I need to be able to specify a different constant (e.g. the 0.8) for each supplier.

I'm thinking I should just use an aggregation with an $out to the same collection, to overwrite the whole then when the update is done, but I can't do a different aggregate() call for each supplier since I'm overwriting the collection - all other suppliers will be skipped. Is there some sort of "in place" aggregation? or a way to append $out ?

Comment: It is possible for you add the constant (ex 0.8) in the initial document ?

Comment: @Koitoer - not easily - in my real case, that value is derived from several data sources and this update will be run regularly by a cron job